# Searching for a word in a nested list

Tags: python, list, search

I am trying to write a function that searches for something specifically in a list:

```
def search(inlist, matches):
    for li in inlist:
        for m in matches:
            if m in li:
                return li
    return none

l = [("daniel", "20th november", "tenochtitlan"), ("Arturo", 17, "17th october")]
```

Here, for example, looking for the birthdate of daniel.

I have this to define the search but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Comment: The title of your question, the code and what you want are different from each others. Explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: When I take this code (removing the broken `return none` or replacing it with the correct but unnecessary `return None`) it seems to do exactly what you want. In particular, `search(l, ['daniel'])` returns `('daniel', '20th november', 'tenochtitlan')`. If that's wrong, then what _do_ you want? Edit your question to give us the input, desired output, and actual output.

Answer (score -1):

From the code written there i got this:

```
l = [("daniel", "20th november", "tenochtitlan"), ("Arturo", 17, "17th october")]
data = search(l, ['daniel'])
#data will be ("daniel", "20th november", "tenochtitlan")
for d in data:
   #regexp to find something specific, return that value
   if SomeRegexp.match(d):
      return d
```

But you will have to be more specific if you want a more specific answer.